# Can't get puppeteer/chromium to cache assets

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, chromium

I have a huge number of jest tests which use puppeteer and jest-environment-puppeteer to load a SPA, then drive certain interactions. The tests take a very long time to run, and after a lot of investigation it seems that a substantial portion of time is taken by the headless browser reloading the page and assets for every test. Since none of this will ever change within the context of a test run, it seems like a lot of wasted effort, so I'm trying to get chromium to cache the page and assets.

The approach the tests use is to create a single browser instance, then load a new page for each test, using request interception to give canned responses (including the static assets).  Here is the puppeteer config:

```js
module.exports = {
  launch: {
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    dumpio: true,
    args: [
      '--disable-software-rasterizer',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
      '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0',
      '--no-zygote',
      '--window-size=1280,1024',
      '--hide-scrollbars',
      '--no-default-browser-check',
      '--no-startup-window',
      '--disable-smooth-scrolling',
      '--enable-font-antialiasing',
      '--disable-background-networking',
      '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
      '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
      '--disable-boot-animation',
      '--disable-breakpad',
      '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
      '--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages',
      '--disable-default-apps',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-features=site-per-process',
      '--disable-hang-monitor',
      '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
      '--disable-low-res-tiling',
      '--disable-popup-blocking',
      '--disable-prompt-on-repost',
      '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
      '--disable-sync',
      '--disable-translate',
      '--metrics-recording-only',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update',
      '--password-store=basic',
      '--use-mock-keychain',
    ],
  },
  browserContext: 'default',
};
```

Within the intercepting request handler, I'm setting `Cache-Control: max-age=604800` in the responses with code that looks like this:

```js
async handleRequest(request) {
    const url = request.url();
    const method = request.method();

    const asset = this.assetRegistry.find(a => a.url === url && a.method === method);
    if (asset) {
      const body = fs.readFileSync(asset.file);
      request.respond({
        status: asset.status || 200,
        contentType: resourceTypes[request.resourceType()] || null,
        headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=604800' },
        body,
      });
      return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have confirmed that the header is set correctly by inspecting the response from `page.goto`.

The html that is rendered is pretty standard, and contains references to the assets using standard tags, e.g.

```html
<link rel="preload" href="<%= staticAssetUrl %>/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= buildAssetUrl %>/app.js"></script>
```

Other things I have checked:

- I am using the latest versions of puppeteer and jest-environment-puppeteer
- I am only creating a single browser instance in global setup
- I have tried explicitly setting `page.setCacheEnabled(true)` (this should be the default anyway)
- The URL requested by the browser is identical for subsequent requests (i.e. no fingerprinting)